# Can org-mode open a link in external browser when using prefix key?

Tags: org-mode, web-browser

In my Emacs I have set `browse-url-browser-function` to `eww` and `org-open-at-point` (`org-return`) will open my links using `eww` as expected.  However, I would like to configure `org-mode` so that when I press prefix + return (`C-u RET`) the link is opened using an external browser instead, is this possible without modifying `org-open-at-point`?

I already have a helper function, `user/browse-url-external`, that I use in other modes to open URL at-point in an external browser instead of `eww`.  It doesn't work with links in `org-mode` since `browse-url` only sees the descriptive text and not the hyperlink.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not directly possible, since `org-open-at-point` already uses the prefix argument for something else.  But of course there's nothing preventing you from wrapping `org-open-at-point` with your own code:

```el
(defun my-org-open-at-point (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (if (not arg)
      (org-open-at-point)
      (let ((browse-url-browser-function #'browse-url-chromium))
        (org-open-at-point))))
```

and binding it to `C-c C-o`:

```el
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-o") #'my-org-open-at-point)
```

Note that I didn't just advise `org-open-at-point`, since I'm a little nervous about changing its behaviour — it might break some other parts of *Org*.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative that should work without any modifications. If you look at the documentation for `org-open-at-point`:

```lisp
(defun org-open-at-point (&optional arg)
  "Open link, timestamp, footnote or tags at point.

When point is on a link, follow it.  Normally, files will be
opened by an appropriate application.  If the optional prefix
argument ARG is non-nil, Emacs will visit the file.  With
a double prefix argument, try to open outside of Emacs, in the
application the system uses for this file type.
```

See that last sentence? Simply pressing `C-u C-u RET` should open any link with a system application rather than in Emacs.

Comment: You probably can't see it, but there is a deleted answer to this question that your answer duplicates. The comments to that deleted answer indicate that the answer does not work. Have you tried it out? I have not, but apparently it does not do what you think it does.

Comment: I don't see a deleted answer. I have tried it out using a PDF and it worked as expected.

Comment: Did you change your `browse-url-browser-function` to `eww` as the question specifies?