# orgmode open link in system browser or eww

Tags: org-mode, eww, web-browser, url

I want orgmode web links to open in my system browser with `C-o`, and to open in eww with `C-u C-o`. This seems in line with the function description for `org-open-at-point` but it doesn't seem to be working. I've tried various permutations of the following, but can't seem to get behavior that allows me to choose between firefox and eww based on `C-u` args. The following seems to always open in eww, regardless.

```
(setq browse-url-generic-program (executable-find "firefox")
      browse-url-browser-function 'eww-browse-url)
```

Comment: You can find a solution for this at: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/11008/can-org-mode-open-a-link-in-external-browser-when-using-prefix-key